# Empty constructor bodies should be written using a ';' rather than '{}'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update my old script that I used to create custom textfield. Its working before nullsafety. But now I'm getting three errors from this script.

```
class TextFieldTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
      final String ?initialValue;
      final bool ?enabled;
      final String labelText;

  const TextFieldTemplate(
      {super.key,
      this.initialValue,
      this.enabled,
      required this.labelText,
}) 
      
  @override
  Future<Widget> build(BuildContext context) async {
    return TextFormField(    
      enabled: enabled,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: labelText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1. `Const constructors can't have a body. Try removing either the 'const' keyword or the body.`
2. `Empty constructor bodies should be written using a ';' rather than '{}'. Try replacing the constructor body with ';'`
3. `'TextFieldTemplate.build' ('Future<Widget> Function(BuildContext)') isn't a valid override of 'StatelessWidget.build' ('Widget Function(BuildContext)')`

Comment: #1 and #2 are not errors.  They are suggestions that you can ignore if you prefer.  They also should be self-explanatory.  For #3, a `build` method cannot be asynchronous.  The `build` method you've shown should never have worked, and there isn't even any need for it to be asynchronous.  Remove the `async` keyword and fix its return type to just `Widget`.

Comment: As indicates @jamesdlin, the warnings and error are self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove async, here is updated version

```
    class TextFieldTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? initialValue;
  final bool? enabled;
  final String labelText;

  const TextFieldTemplate({
    super.key,
    this.initialValue,
    this.enabled,
    required this.labelText,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // Removed async from here
    return TextFormField(
      enabled: enabled,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: labelText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```